# How to solve gradle contains too many directories

Tags: react-native, gradle

I'm trying to code with react native. My android studio is ready. When I open the android project from my react native file, android studio builds the gradle successfully.

My virtual device is ready too. When I execute run-android in cmd for my react native file, I am faced with this error:

> gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5.1-all.zip **contains too many directories**.expected to find exactly 1 directory.

This error does not change, even when I downloaded gradle manually and placed it in `.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.5.1-all` the error was the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think its far too late for you but I had the same error. 
Turns out that the folder had multiple versions of gradle inside distributions.
I removed the ones i did not need and it worked like a charm.
The key is there should be exactly 1 version(or folder) for gradle under distributions.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's kinda too late but: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>
and set Android Gradle plugin version on last version.